# jQuery to refresh in real time, without waiting for a focus change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple calculator script. When the number in the input changes, the original amount is multiplied. **Everything works great, but I want it to change in real time.**

In other words, right now the `multiplier()` is executed `on ("click")`, but I want it to be executed instantly on input change.

```js
var multiplier = function() {
  var original = parseInt($('#original').html());
  original *= parseInt($('#theinput').val());
  $("#multiplied").text(original);
}

$(document).on('click', function() {
  multiplier();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>The input:</b> <input type="number" id="theinput" value="1">
<br /><br />
<b>Original amount:</b> <span id="original">500</span>
<br /><br />
<b>Multiplied:</b> <span id="multiplied">500</span>
```

Comment: you can use `ìnput` event  instead of  `click` event.

Comment: `$('#theinput').on('input', multiplier);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to sum values in jquery with realtime calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515502/how-to-sum-values-in-jquery-with-realtime-calculation)

Answer (score 0):

My better approach is to use `oninput` element like this:

**e.g.**

```js
var multiplier = function() {
  var original = parseInt($('#original').html());
  original *= parseInt($('#theinput').val());
  $("#multiplied").text(original);
}

function call_function(){
  multiplier();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>The input:</b> <input type="number" id="theinput" value="1" oninput="call_function()">
<br /><br />
<b>Original amount:</b> <span id="original">500</span>
<br /><br />
<b>Multiplied:</b> <span id="multiplied">500</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Chris G**'s comment is obviously the most simple and straightforward solution. Since he didn't write answer himself, I'll do it myself.

`$('#theinput').on('input', multiplier);` is the solution.

```js
var multiplier = function() {
  var original = parseInt($('#original').html());
  original *= parseInt($('#theinput').val());
  $("#multiplied").text(original);
}

$('#theinput').on('input', multiplier);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>The input:</b> <input type="number" id="theinput" value="1">
<br /><br />
<b>Original amount:</b> <span id="original">500</span>
<br /><br />
<b>Multiplied:</b> <span id="multiplied">500</span>
```